# How to return an MD5 and SHA1 value for multiple files in a directory using BASH

Tags: bash

I am creating a BASH script to take a directory as an argument and return to std out a list of all files in that directory with both the MD5 and SHA1 value of the files present in that directory. The only files I'm interested in are those between 100 and 500K. So far I gotten this far. (Section of Script)

```
cd $1 &&
find . -type f -size +100k -size -500k -printf '%f \t %s \t' -exec md5sum {} \; |
awk '{printf "NAME:" " " $1 "\t" "MD5:" " " $3 "\t" "BYTES:" "\t" $2 "\n"}'
```

I'm getting a little confused when adding the Sha1 and obviously leaving something out.

Can anybody suggest a way to achieve this.

Ideally I'd like the script to format in the following way

Name          Md5                 SHA1

(With the relevant fields underneath)

Comment: `Ideally I'd like the script to format in the following way` - then why do you print those `NAME:` and `MD5:` and `BYTES:`? Why `-printf %s`?

Comment: That was a previous version where I was outputting size also. Apologies.

Comment: I suppose something like this:
printf "NAME\t\t\t\t\tMD5\t\t\t\t\tSHA1\n"
        find . -type f -printf "%f" -exec md5sum {} \; | awk '{ printf " %s  %s  %s\n", $1, $3, $2 }'

but obviously with SHA1 instead of repeating the filename at the end

Comment: Why do you put so many `\t`?

Comment: I'm trying to format it (and failing) so that files and hashes are more presentable when outputted to a report file. Which is the end goal. Different length file names push the hashes all over the place making it look dis-organised. I'd like all the hashes to fall under each other ideally.

Comment: Use `column` to format a table.

Comment: Thanks KamilCuk. I'll look into that!! Appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `awk` `printf` bit is overly complicated. Try this:

```
find . -type f -printf "%f\t%s\t" -exec md5sum {} \; | awk '{ printf "NAME: %s MD5: %s BYTES: %s\n", $1, $3, $2 }'
```

Comment: Appreciate the input, any idea how to add a SHA1 to this so as to print file name md5 and sha1 of every file in the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Just read line by line the list of files outputted by `find`:

```
find . -type f |
while IFS= read -r l; do
   echo "$(basename "$l") $(md5sum <"$l" | cut -d" " -f1) $(sha1sum <"$l" | cut -d" " -f1)"
done
```

It's better to use a zero separated stream:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' l; do
   echo "$(basename "$l") $(md5sum <"$l" | cut -d" " -f1) $(sha1sum <"$l" | cut -d" " -f1)"
done
```

You could speed up something with `xargs` and multiple processes with `-P` option to `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 -n1 sh -c 'echo "$(basename "$1") $(md5sum <"$1" | cut -d" " -f1) $(sha1sum <"$1" | cut -d" " -f1)"' --
```

Consider adding `-maxdepth 1` to `find` if you are not interested in files in subdirectories recursively.

It's easy from `xargs` to go to `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$1 $(md5sum <"$1" | cut -d" " -f1) $(sha1sum <"$1" | cut -d" " -f1)"' -- {} \;
```

[Tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/OldlacePlayfulCron).

Add those `-size +100k -size -500k` args to `find` to limit the sizes.

The `| cut -d" " -f1` is used to remove the `-` that is outputted by both `md5sum` and `sha1sum`. **If** there are no spaces in filenames, you could run a single `cut` process for the whole stream, so it should be slightly faster:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 -n1 sh -c 'echo "$(basename "$1") $(md5sum <"$1") $(sha1sum <"$1")"' -- |
cut -d" " -f1,2,5
```

I also think that running a single `md5sum` and `sha1sum` process maybe would be faster rather then spawning multiple separate processes for each file, but such method needs storing all the filenames somewhere. Below a bash array is used:

```
IFS=$'\n' files=($(find . -type f))
paste -d' ' <(
    printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}") <(
    md5sum "${files[@]}" | cut -d' ' -f1) <(
    sha1sum "${files[@]}" | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

Comment: Awesome! I was going blind looking at this. 
That's exactly what I was looking for !!

Could I pick your brain on one more thing, perhaps you could help.

When I run that command it executes as expected. The last thing I would like to do is format the output so all the hashes align. At present they are affected by the filename length. A longer filename pushes the hash further to the right if you understand what I mean??/?

Comment: Yes, pipe it to something along `column -t -s' '`. If you have spaces in filenames, choose another separator.

Comment: I don't have any spaces in filenames.
'code'
find . -type f  -print0 |
                while IFS= read -r -d '' l; do
                           echo  "$(basename "$l") $(md5sum <"$l") $(sha1sum <"$l")" | column -t -s" "
                   done
'code'
Doesn't work. (Formatting isn't affected)
I can research columns and hopefully get it to work.
I've taken up enough of your time.
Appreciate everything you've helped with so far!!!!!
Absolute Gent!!

Comment: You are missing those ` | cut -d" " -f1` after md5 and sha1. "Doesn't work" is very vague, please try to be specific. What does it mean that it "does not work"?

Comment: find . -type f -print0 |
                xargs -0 -n1 sh -c 'echo "$(basename "$1") $(md5sum <"$1") $(sha1sum <"$1")"' -- |
                cut -d" " -f1,3,5 | column -t -s' '


This formats correctly - but does not output the SHA1SUM

I'm obviously doing something stupid

Comment: Arg right, should be `cut -d' ' -f1,2,5`. Or `tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1,2,4`

Comment: Savage!!!
Thanks a million for all your help.
A lot of research follows for me to understand fully!!!!
Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your find is fine, you want to join the results of two of those, one for each hash. The command for that is `join`, which expects sorted inputs.

```
doit() { find -type f -size +100k -size -500k -exec $1 {} + |sort -k2; }
join -j2 <(doit md5sum) <(doit sha1sum)
```

and that gets you the raw data in sane environments. If you want pretty data, you can use the `column` utility:

```
join -j2 <(doit md5sum) <(doit sha1sum) | column -t
```

and add nice headers:

```
(echo Name Md5 SHA1; join -j2 <(doit md5sum) <(doit sha1sum)) | column -t
```

and if you're in an unclean environment where people put spaces in file names, protect against that by subbing in tabs for the field markers:

```
doit() { find -type f -size +100k -size -500k -exec $1 {} + \
         | sed 's,  ,\t,'| sort -k2 -t$'\t' ; }
join -j2 -t$'\t' <(doit md5sum) <(doit sha1sum) | column -ts$'\t'
```